# Thymeleaf não reconhece ROLES do Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

Olá, tenho uma aplicação com Spring Security, atualmente ela já funciona de forma dinâmica, tendo as seguintes classes Models:

Classe User:

```
public class User {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String nome;
private String email;
private String fone;
private String cidade;
private String estado;
private String pais;
private String cep;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Empresa empresa;

private boolean disabled = false;
private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

//Gets/Sets e Construtores

}
```

Classe Role

```
public class Role {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long id;
private String roleName;

//Gets/Sets e Construtores

}
```

Através da tela de Login consigo fazer login normalmente.
Pórem, após logado, não consigo utilizar o comando Thymeleaf para bloquear conteúdos com base na ROLE (permissão). Ou seja, não funciona e precisaria de ajuda quanto a isso.

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''engcomp'')')}">
  ADMIn section
</div>      
        
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''[engcomp]'')')}">
  This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
</div>      
        
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('[engcomp]')">
 ENG_COMP
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('[ENG_MEC]')">
 ENG_MEC
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('[GERENTE]')">
 GERENTE
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('[OPERADOR]')">
 OPERADOR
</div>
```

Mas se eu rodo o comando abaixo, me retorna o nome da permissão do determinado usuário:

```
<div th:text="${#authentication.name}">
 </div>
```

Retornando: engcomp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você precise criar uma classe que implemente `UserDetailsService`.

Esta interface tem um método chamado `loadUserByUsername` que é chamado quando um usuário está fazendo um login. Dentro deste método você monta um objeto `UserDetails` com as roles que usuário possuir e devolve para o Spring.

Particularmente eu prefiro fazer desta forma, como por exemplo está neste [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) e também neste [projeto no github](https://github.com/gustavoponce7/spring-login/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gpch/login/service/MyUserDetailsService.java), como por exemplo:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FunctionaryDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private FunctionaryRepository functionaryRepository;


    @Override
    public FunctionaryUser loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        Functionary functionary = functionaryRepository.findByEmail(email);
        
        //... 
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(functionary.getUserRole().name()));

        List<Accomplishment> atrasosList = accomplishmentRepository.findAtrasadosPorFuncionario(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1), functionary);

       /*
         neste caso FunctionaryUser é uma classe que implementa org.springframework.security.core.userdetails;
        */
        FunctionaryUser user = new FunctionaryUser(functionary, true, true, true, true, authorities);
        
        return user;
    }
    
}
```

A documentação do Spring sobre [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.2/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice) é um bom lugar também para consultar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Apesar de conter um link, seria bom inserir as partes essenciais para a solução do problema. Links podem se tornar inválidos e repositórios no github podem ser removidos.

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação, @Danizavtz . Vou tentar melhorar.